# Reference an Attribute from Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm setting this attribute in my Lightning Aura component:

```
<aura:attribute name="myAttribute" type="object" />
```

This component is a "helper" utility component that other components reference. I'd like to be able to dynamically reference a custom field within `myAttribute` from a different component's controller:

```
if (myAttribute.My_Custom_Field__c == true) {
    // do something
}
```

But this isn't working. How can I dynamically reference this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make this helper "utility" component as extendable so as to make the `helper.js` shared across components.

For example consider below `utilityHelper.js`:

```
({
    myAttribute: {
        My_Custom_Field__c: 'some value',
        My_Boolean_Field__c: false,
    }
})
```

Now when you [extend](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_cmp_attributes.htm) this `utility` component and you can access the new/modified values as below:

`testCompController.js`:

```
({
    myAction: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        let myBoolean = helper.myAttribute.My_Boolean_Field__c;
        helper.myAttribute.My_Custom_Field__c = 'changed value'; // can be accessed in any other component controller/helper.js which extends utility component
    }
})
```